# Changes in Javascript not being reflected while debugging Web page

Tags: javascript, php, nginx

I am working on a web page development using netbeans IDE and use Firefox for debugging/testing. Whenever i do changes to Javascript, these changes are not getting reflected on the web page,the source code reveals the obsolete code.

Everytime i make changes, i ensure to restart my nginx server before opening browser, PHP seems to work fine this way, but Javascript is not in sync with my changes to the code.

Pls provide me a solution to encounter this problem.

Comment: Your browser is caching the js files. Either you need to clear your browser or add header in js files for not caching. Google caching for more details.

Comment: @Panther is right, you can also use `ctrl + F5` to force the browser to reload

Comment: thanks @Panther,@LuthandoLoot  i made programmetical changes by adding header, now its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your **browser is caching your files**, you can clean browser caching or set the browser to stop caching files.

Another way to avoid browser caching is **append** something (timestamp or id) with a **'?'** at the end of your **HTML** file reference.

```
<script src='script.js?0001'><script>
```

Any time you want the browser request your file again, just change this value.

Comment: that helps, thank you :-) But how to generate a random number everytime?

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding the caching of files, its better to handle it programatticlly by adding proper headers like Cache-Control and max-age. However, these headers are different for different browser like IE ,firefox etc.

Best way is to trick browser by adding the randow query parameter so that browser will belive this is different request.

```
<script src='myScript.js?dummyParam=12001>
```

Here,12001 should be generated different after every change by using timestamp or someother random value.